# Converting 16-bit RGB values to one decimal value

Tags: javascript, colors, bit-manipulation

I designed an "ESOLANG" which uses 16-bit color and a sprite editor (the one the post is about JS, HTML.), the thing is that i tried converting it using r×g×b but it only works if the values are 32×64×32, i also tried this

```
var components = {
    r: (c & 0b1111100000000000) >> 16, 
    g: (c & 0b0000011111100000) >> 8, 
    b: (c & 0b0000000000011111)
```

but it made me realize that i'm not that good at bit manipulation, the thing is supposed to be a sprite editor with load and save from text, like each rows each columns 16-bit RGB as a single decimal value. I even had no luck searching the interweb for the answer i needed. Most of it was about 24-bit colour, which uses 8 bits for each color channel, whilist 16-bit RGB uses 5 red channels, 6 green channels due to the human's eye sensitivity to green and 5 blue channels. It should fit in about 2 bytes (0xFFFF) but the standard approach which is what i posted as code but using hexadecimal values, wouldn't work in this scenario. Any help is kindly appreciated.
EDIT:
i tried this, and by the way, i feel a bit embarassed for asking for help, when the solution could be simpler than i actually tried

```
 data.value = "";
 for(var x=0;x<16;x++){
  for(var y=0;y<16;y++){
    var components = {
    r: (tile[x][y][0] & 1111100000000000) >> 11, 
    g: (tile[x][y][1] & 0000011111100000) >> 5, 
    b: (tile[x][y][2] & 0000000000011111)
    };
    data.value = data.value + (components.r << 11) + (components.g << 5) + (components.b) + " ";
  }
    data.value = data.value + "\n";
 }
 
}
```

I used 31,63,31 (WHITE in 16-bit), which should output about 65535 but instead it outputs 009 as the output.

Comment: You want to split a 16 bit number into 3 parts, 5, 6, and 5 respective to RGB? Maybe an example or two showing the original 16 bit value and the result values you expect would help. Right shifting a 16-bit number by 16 chops all the bits off, so you probably just want to shift by 11 and 5 respective to R and G, which is what harold said above.

Comment: Edited, i feel embarrased that i didn't calculate such simple thing.

Comment: why do you try to extract the r,g and b channels from three different values `tile[x][y][???]`, thought this was a single 16bit integer? oh, and btw, `0000000000011111 === 4681` not `31`. This is an octal value.